# Trying to eliminate white space at end of the lines and then merge (\1) and (\3) by eliminating (\2) (CR/LF)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Trying to take the below lines and make
Group 1: `Ltm::.....` until end of line of text.
Group 2: Whitespace/CR/LF AFTER group 1 all the way until Group 3
Group 3: `Availability      : available` or whatever the status is.

Data Source:

```
Ltm::Virtual Server: dmz.abc.com_443  
  Availability     : available  
Ltm::Virtual Server: dmztest.abc.com_80  
  Availability     : unknown     
Ltm::Virtual Server: dmztest.abc.com_443  
  Availability     : available   
Ltm::Virtual Server: lop.abc.com_80  
  Availability     : unknown     
Ltm::Virtual Server: lop.abc.com_443  
  Availability     : available
```

My search is this:

```
(Ltm::.*_.*\s)(\r\n|\N)(\s.*$)
```

And my replace is `(\1)(\3)` which effectively (I thought) would eliminate my group 2 match of all the crap hidden CR/LF

Comment: Your question misses the **question** part.

Comment: Here worked fine just removing the |\N part of the regex. Regex = `(Ltm::.*_.*\s)(\r\n)(\s.*$)`

Comment: [`(Ltm::.*_.*?(?=\s))\s*(.*?)\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/PrmuDv/1), perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this pattern:

```
(Ltm:.*)\s*\r?\n\s*(Availability.+)
```

Explanation:

`(...)` - store matched text in capturing group

`.*` - match zero or more of arbitrary characters (except newline)

`\s*` - match zero or more whitespaces

`\r?` - match 0 or 1 carriage return

`\n` - match newline

Here you would match carriage return optionally which then could match both LF and CRLF.

At the end just replace it with first and second capturing group: `$1$2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xOJHnW/1)

**EDIT**

As suggested by AdrianHHH, in comments, in Notepad++ you can use `\R` to match any newline character with or without carriage return; see the [Notepad++ user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#special-control-escapes).

Comment: In Notepad++ one can use `\R` to mean any of the various newline sequences. So can use `\R` instead of `\r?\n`.

Comment: Search for "Special Control escapes" within https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/

Answer (score 1):

It is really dependent on the editor you are using. You say you use this regex:

`(Ltm::.*_.*\s)(\r\n|\N)(\s.*$)`

to identify multi lines
But when working with multi lines, the special ^ and $ still stop at each line start/end.
If you want to identify the start and end of the matched string you should use \A (start of the string) and \Z (end of the string)
Your regex would work if written as:

```
^\s*(Ltm::.*)\s*(\n)$^(\s|\r|\n)*(Availability.*)\s*(\n)$
```

This will match one instance in your list
If you search and replace each instance by \1\2\4\5, it will get rid of the invisible "junk".
If you suspect there is junk somewhere else, replace the \s* by (\s|\r|\n)* to make sure it is also deleted. Notice the (\n) groups before the end of line, you need to keep this newline, because in multiline \s matches \n as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your example data has at least 2 "spaces" after each line, your pattern will have these matches:

- `(Ltm::.*_.*\s)` Capture **group 1**, this part matches the whole line, and as `\s` can also match a newline, it will match that as well
- `(\r\n|\N)` Capture **group 2**, this part will match the first whitespace char on the next line due to `\N` that matches any non newline char
- `(\s.*$)` Capture **group 3**, this part will match the second space on the next line followed by the rest of the line

So if you replace with `\1\3` you still have the newline that is captured in group 1 and the part that you will leave out is the single non newline character that was matched by `\N`

---

A possible solution might be:

**Find what:**

```
^(\h*Ltm::.*_\d+)\h*\R\h*(\h.*\S)\h*
```

**Replace with:**

```
\1\2
```

Or if you want to keep the parenthesis in the replacement using Notepad++, you have to escape them:

```
\(\1\)\(\2\)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(\h*Ltm::.*_\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match optional leading horizontal whitespace chars and then `Ltm::` Then `.*` will match the rest of the line followed by the last occurrence of `_` and 1+ digits
- `\h*\R\h*` Match any Unicode newline sequence surrounded by optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\h.*\S)` Capture **group 2**, match a single horizontal whitespace char, the rest of the line and then the last non whitespace character
- `\h*` Match optional trailing horizontal whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DoCYy8/1).

[image]